# Is there a way to get which group is the one that matched in a regex. Prefer Javascript but Python OK too.

Tags: javascript, python

Is there a way to get which group matches a regex?

for example (using js but could be re-expressed in Python etc):

`

```
myRegex = /(this)|(that)|(other)/ig    //describes 3 group captures
// The groups number (this==0, that==1, other==2)  --> I'd like to get the capturing group number returned in the matches.

myString = "this is awesome cause that is the other thing this needs"

//result desired
getMyMatchesByCaptureIndex(myRegex,myString)  // function I'd like help with

//returns a result like this...
[
  //[indexOfGroup, indexOfBeginningOfMatch, lengthOfMatch]...
  [0, 0,  4],     //a group 0 match at position 0  length of 4
  [1, 22, 4],     //a group 1 match at position 22 length of 4
  [2, 34, 4],     //a group 2 match at position 34 length of 4
  [0, 46, 5]      //a group 0 match at position 46 length of 5
]
```

`

Prefer Javascript or Python if possible and allow more than 9 groups.  My simplified example could include more complex regex constructs inside the parenthesis but I used strings just for simplicity of asking.  (e.g. instead of (this) could be (t[0-9][A-F]...) etc)  so I'd really like this to be a regex or parser centric answer if possible!

Thanks much!

Comment: .exec with a loop in js

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and [`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) to get all the information in one go:

```
function matchesByCaptureIndex(regex, text) {
  var match = null, result = [];
  while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
    var matchedGroup = match.slice(1).indexOf(match[0]);
    var matchLength = match[0].length;
    var startIndex = regex.lastIndex - matchLength;
    result.push([matchedGroup, startIndex, matchLength]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: matchLength should be `match[0].length`